# Facebook Open Graph event search

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

On Graph API Explorer I can do this search: search?q=Barcelona&type=event

But when I try the same with my app access token I get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

The other searches work well.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2017-11-27:**
As Facebook doesn't allow an event search based on location anymore, I'd recommend to use https://github.com/tobilg/facebook-events-by-location-core

**Original answer:**

Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#access_tokens

There, it's stated that all searches except for pages and places require an **user** access token.